# Determine the probability density function for $Y=X^2$.

Tags: probability, statistics

> **Question:** Let $X\sim U(0,1)$.Determine the probability density function of the following variable $Y=X^2$.

Defining the p.d.f for $X$ we have $f_X(x)=\begin{cases}0\:\:if\:x\notin[0,1]\\1\:\:if\:x\in[0,1]\end{cases}$

I know that $E(Y)=\int_\limits{R}{}g(x)f_x(x)dx=\int_\limits{0}^{1} x^2\times 1=\frac{1}{2}$, for $Y=g(X)=X^2$

$Var(Y)=E(Y^2)-(E(Y))^2=\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{9}=\frac{4}{45}$

According to my resolution the p.d.f should remain the same $f_X(x)=\begin{cases}0\:\:if\:x\notin[0,1]\\1\:\:if\:x\in[0,1]\end{cases}$.

**Question**: What is the point of askin the p.d.f for $Y$? Or is my answer wrong? If so, why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmmm... E(Y) and Var(Y) certainly do not suffice to determine the PDF of Y, so why mention them? // No, the PDF of Y is not the PDF of X, why should it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea why do you compute expectation of $Y$ but

$$\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx = \frac13 $$

The density must have changed.

A possible way to find pdf is to first find the CDF then differentiate it to find pdf:

Let $y \in (0,1)$,
\begin{align}
Pr(Y \le y) &= Pr(X^2 \le y) \\
&= Pr( X \le \sqrt{y})
\end{align}

Can you complete the task?

Edit:

$$F_Y(y) = \begin{cases} 0 & ,y < 0\\
\sqrt{y} &, y \in [0,1) \\
1 &, y \ge 1
 \end{cases}$$

Comment: Please could you finish the exercise. I am trying to do it but I am not getting it right. I need to see an example first. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: can you show me what do you have currently? I can try to fix your error. what do you have for $Pr(X \le \sqrt{y})$ when $y \in (0,1)$?

Comment: $P(X\leqslant\sqrt{y})=F(\sqrt{y})=\int_\limits{0}^{\sqrt{y}}1dx=\sqrt{y}$. I am stuck, I do not know how to build the cdf.

Comment: Hey, you are doing it great so far. You just have to differentiate it, i.e. $\frac{d}{dy} \sqrt{y}$ to get the pdf.

Comment: My problem is with the intervals. How do I define the cdf?

Comment: I edited the answer to include the CDF.

Comment: Thanks! I have managed to solve it!